# delete a row in json array in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

guys i know it is dummy question but i spent lot of hours in this and still cant reach .. i am trying to draw a textboxes and set there id through iteration .. i did draw them but failed to set their ids .. here is my code

```
GridLibrary.prototype.display = function() {
var html = [];
check = startIndex;
html.push("<table id='table'>\n<body>");
html.push("<tr><th>Delete</th>");
for ( var propertyNames in this.data[0]) {

    html.push("<th>" + propertyNames + "</th>");
}
html.push("</tr>");
// loop through the array of objects
var item;
for (var i = startIndex; i < endIndex; i++) {
    item = this.data[i];
    html.push("<tr><td><input type='checkbox' id='chk_"+check+"'/></td>");
    check++;
    console.log(check);
    for ( var key in item) {
        html.push("<td>" + item[key] + "</td>");
    }
    html.push("</tr>");

}
html.push("</body>\n</table>");
$('body').append(html.join(""));

};
```

Comment: where is startIndex defined??

Comment: it is set in the same file to set the items i want to display

Comment: I don't get it. Look - https://jsbin.com/xumuramopu/edit?html,js,output. All is ok. They have proper ids.

Comment: And you are saying that you are trying to draw textboxes, so where is that ?? I can see checkbox